# Get the text value from ASP.NET Hyperlink

Tags: jquery, gridview, datagridview

I'm trying to figure out how to use jquery to get the text out of an asp.net gridview hyperlink text.

```
<asp:GridView ID="g" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"  OnRowCreated="g_RowCreated" OnRowDataBound="g_RowDataBound" Width="755px" >
<Columns>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left" ItemStyle-Width="100%">
        <ItemTemplate>                                              
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="javascript://" onclick="<%# Eval(&quot;varId&quot;, &quot;return loadData('{0}',this);&quot;)%>" Text='<%# Eval("varName","{0}") %>' ></asp:HyperLink>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Hyperlink1 the text value I want to grab that so I can use it as a column heading some where else on my page.  Is there a way to use jquery for this?  I've already know that using the getElementById wont work so what is after that?  I'm trying to get this text value so I can make it my jquery dialog title name.

Thanks

Comment: Where do you want to access it?

Comment: I'd like to access it in the HTML

Comment: I mean where, when, during which event? or is it in `loadData`?

Comment: For starters, since you're using jQuery then you're writing client-side code.  So you'll want to examine the resulting client-side HTML instead of the server-side control markup.

Comment: It is important to know where you are trying to access it. If it is withing the loadData, you already have the context of the element passed in as argument. if outside inspect your element, your id will not be the same as what you specified (thanks to asp.net), provide a class name or even use the clientId to select it.

Comment: Show where you did `getElementById` as well. Please post what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the result of that server-side markup inside your `onclick` attribute is going to be, nor do I know what your client-side markup ends up being.  (Posting these things will really help.)  But if you're in the context of a click event handler for the hyperlink then you can get its text with [jQuery's `.text()` function](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

For example, if your click handler is something like this:

```
$('table a').click(function () {
    // this is where you want the text
});
```

Then you can reference it by referencing `this` inside the handler:

```
$('table a').click(function () {
    var theText = $(this).text();
});
```

A lot of this is conjecture based on *very* limited information you've provided, I'm just trying to point you in the right direction.  If you can supply your client-side markup and the JavaScript code you're currently using, I can more precisely direct this answer.